# How to combine arrays of monoid type?

Tags: arrays, scala, monoids, scala-cats

A list or array of monoid type `A` is a monoid too. Now I would like to `combine` arrays of integers using `cats`.

```
scala> 1 |+| 2
res1: Int = 3

scala> Array(1, 2, 3) |+| Array(1, 2, 3)
<console>:21: error: value |+| is not a member of Array[Int]
   Array(1, 2, 3) |+| Array(1, 2, 3)
```

I would like to get `Array(2, 4, 6)` as a result of `Array(1, 2, 3) |+| Array(1, 2, 3)` instead. How can I do that ?

Comment: That's not really what `|+|` is for. It's meant to be an append operation. What happens if the arrays aren't the same size?

Comment: _A list or array of monoid type A is a monoid too_ this is in theory but you need to actually provide a `Monoid[Array]` in code e.g. via an `implicit`.

Comment: @MichaelZajac Thanks. I was probably wrong. Array of monoid is probably not a monoid.

Comment: Note, there is an operation called `merge` in Scalaz that does exactly what you want: https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/fabab8f699d56279d6f2cc28d02cc2b768e314d7/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Align.scala#L33
I think, they just didn't port it to `cats` yet.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov Oh, thanks. Good to know. I will check if it exists in `cats`.

Comment: @Michael I already checked and didn't find :( Also, I didn't find a `Monoid` instance for `Array`.

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe they did not port it for a reason ...

Comment: @Michael Indeed, I think it was a conscious decision by the maintainers to exclude it, as it is not a widely used collection type in Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`combine` on a `Seq` or an `Array` usually means appending them to create a new Collection.

However, you can do what you're trying to do by defining your own `Monoid`, with `zip` instead of `append`. Here's something I came up with on the fly:

```
implicit val zipArrayMonoid = new Monoid[Array[Int]] {
  override def combine(x: Array[Int], y: Array[Int]) = {
    x.zip(y).map {
      case (a, b) => a + b
    }
  }

  override def empty = Array.empty
}
```

This will cause arrays of different sizes to have their additional values ignored (as that's what the `zip` implementation does, you can check the docs [here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps.html#zip[B](that:scala.collection.GenIterable[B]):Array[(A,B)]))

Here's a scalaFiddle with the result: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/YzdUl4L/0

Comment: Thanks ! but what if the arrays are not of the same size ?

Comment: That instance violates every single monoid law.

Comment: It does, but I don't see how to implement a Monoid instance for his use case without violating them.